# Fluid padding? Unable to use height or width

Tags: javascript, css, html, forms

I am modifying a `html form` input for uploading files (*input type"file"*), but for some reason I am unable to modify the **height** & **width** of this element to make it 100% of the webpage (*fluid*).

I found an alternative to using the height & width which is using the elements padding. The downside to using the padding is that I simply cannot make it fluid as such, because when I use 100% it is greater than the device viewport. But if I change it to about 50% it is still greater than the device viewport.

I am looking for a solution for this, I **highly doubt** that this question will be solved and I am expecting answers saying that it cant be done but there is no harm in asking.

**My Html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>   
<link href="master.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post">
<input id="form" type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="myFile"/>
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#form {
    padding-top: 50%; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    background-color: green;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's notoriously difficult and not advised to style `input` fields. Instead, create a `label` and attach it to the `input` using the `for` attribute, and style the `label` instead

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

form,label {
  height: 100%;
}

#form {
  padding-top: 50%; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}

label {
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post">
  <label for="form"></label>
  <input id="form" type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="myFile"/>
</form>
```